# parsing output from nm command with awk - Linux Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, nm

I working on some code optimization and I would to inspect the size of my functions instead to read huge disassembly file. After compilation on Debug, I use the nm command to read the .o. We got this :

```
nm --size-sort $OBJFILEPATH.o

000000000000000b r __PRETTY_FUNCTION__.6473
0000000000000017 t extract_h
0000000000000036 t L_mult
000000000000003a t sature32
0000000000000042 t L_mac
0000000000000048 t L_add
000000000000005c t Mac16x11
0000000000000077 t L_shl
0000000000000083 t L_shr
00000000000000df T G729Convolve
0000000000000114 T G729Residu
00000000000001bc T G729Syn_filt_L_H
00000000000001bc T G729Syn_filt_L_SUBFR
```

Now, into a bash script I would like to parse only the 1st column wich each line represent a single array element in bash.

My command will be :

```
read FUNCSIZE <<< $(nm --size-sort $OBJFILEPATH.o | awk '{print $1}')
```

And for make sure that everything is ok I check the size of my FUNCSIZE array.

```
SIZE=${#FUNCSIZE[@]}
echo size is $SIZE
for s in $FUNCSIZE
do
    echo $s
done
```

I got this as output:

```
size is 1
000000000000000b
0000000000000017
0000000000000036
000000000000003a
0000000000000042
0000000000000048
000000000000005c
0000000000000077
0000000000000083
00000000000000df
0000000000000114
00000000000001bc
00000000000001bc
```

Why size is '1' and why I'm able to print each element like it was inside an array. It's seem that the output still have a 'space' ' ' at the end of the line. Is there any RegEx with awk that will avoid to include the separator field into the array?

Thank for your help !!

**EDIT AFTER ANSWER**

```
read -a FUNCSIZE <<< $(nm --size-sort $OBJFILEPATH.o | awk '{print $1}')
SIZE=${#FUNCSIZE[*]}
for((i=0; i<SIZE; i++))
do
    echo ${FUNCSIZE[$i]}
done
```

Comment: You're reading into a scalar, not an array. Maybe you meant to use `read -a`. In any case though, creating a bash array is probably the wrong starting point for whatever it is you're going to do next - if you tell us about that with a concise, testable example we can help you.

Comment: We want to make a tool that ill compare two different .o file and compare if any function have been changed in time. Parsing the size into a variable will the script able to check if a specific function is bigger then before.

Comment: That'd be an awk script so starting off with 2 shell arrays wouldn't be useful. A shell is just an environment from which to call tools with a language to sequence those calls and the standard, general purpose UNIX tool to manipulate text is awk.

Comment: This piece of code represent actually a function inside a shell script, but you're right. I'll use awk instead. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds from your comment like this might be what you're really looking for:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    size = strtonum("0x"$1)
    sub(/^([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){2}/,"")
    name = $0
}
NR==FNR { oldSize[name] = size; next }
{
    newSize[name] = size
    if ( name in oldSize ) {
        if ( oldSize[name] < newSize[name] ) {
            bigger[name]
        }
        else if ( oldSize[name] > newSize[name] ) {
            smaller[name]
        }
    }
    else {
        added[name]
    }
}
END {
   print "Got bigger:"
   for (name in bigger) print "\t" name, oldSize[name], "->", newSize[name]

   print "Got smaller:"
   for (name in smaller) print "\t" name, oldSize[name], "->", newSize[name]

   print "Added:"
   for (name in added) print "\t" name

   print "Deleted:"
   for (name in oldSize) if ( !(name in newSize) ) print "\t" name
}
```

.

```
$ gawk -f tst.awk <(cat file1) <(cat file2)
Got bigger:
    Mac16x11 92 -> 93
Got smaller:
    L_mac 66 -> 65
Added:
    extract_h
Deleted:
    G729Residu
```

The above uses GNU awk for strtonum() and was run on these 2 input files:

```
$ cat file1
000000000000000b r __PRETTY_FUNCTION__.6473
0000000000000036 t L_mult
000000000000003a t sature32
0000000000000042 t L_mac
0000000000000048 t L_add
000000000000005c t Mac16x11
0000000000000077 t L_shl
0000000000000083 t L_shr
00000000000000df T G729Convolve
0000000000000114 T G729Residu
00000000000001bc T G729Syn_filt_L_H
00000000000001bc T G729Syn_filt_L_SUBFR

$ cat file2
000000000000000b r __PRETTY_FUNCTION__.6473
0000000000000017 t extract_h
0000000000000036 t L_mult
000000000000003a t sature32
0000000000000041 t L_mac
0000000000000048 t L_add
000000000000005d t Mac16x11
0000000000000077 t L_shl
0000000000000083 t L_shr
00000000000000df T G729Convolve
00000000000001bc T G729Syn_filt_L_H
00000000000001bc T G729Syn_filt_L_SUBFR
```

Just replace each `cat file` with the corresponding `nm ...`.

Comment: Awesome Ed Morton !!

Answer (score 2):

The way you wrote it, `FUNCSIZE` is not an array, but a regular variable.

Add the `-a` flag for `read`:

```
read -a FUNCSIZE <<< $(nm --size-sort $OBJFILEPATH.o | awk '{print $1}')
```

Note that using all-uppercase names for user-defined variables is not recommended, to [avoid conflicts (and confusion) with environmental variables and special shell variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_01).

*(Thanks [@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) for the tips and links!)*

Comment: Thank you janos and Ed Morton. The -a flag was the answer I was looking for !!

Comment: I suggest either not showing the `FUNCSIZE=( $(...) )` alternative at all, or calling it out as an anti-pattern, because it makes the command substitution's output subject to (typically unwanted) globbing (try `a=( $(echo '*') )`. It's also worth recommending not to use all-uppercase variable names, and to routinely add the `-r` option to `read`.